# r large data.table why is extracting a word with regex faster than stringr::word?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, stringr

I have a large data.table with over 7 million rows and 38 columns.  One of the columns is a character vector, which contains a long descriptive sentence.  I know that the first word of each sentence is a category and the second word is a name, both of which I need to put in two new columns for later analysis.

This probably won't illustrate the time differences too well as it is too small (actually `system.time()` on this example gives 0), but here is a toy character string to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
# Load libraries:
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

# Create example character string:
x <- c("spicy apple cream", "mild peach melba", "juicy strawberry tart")
id <- c(1,2,3)

# Create dt:
mydt <- data.table(id = id, desert = x)
```

Supposing as in my real data, I want to extract the first word from each string, and put it in a new variable called category, then the second word from each string and put it in a new variable called fruit_name.

The lexically simplest way seems to be to use `stringr::word()` which is appealing because it avoids the need for working out complicated regular expressions:

```
# Add a new category column:
mydt[, category := stringr::word(desert, 1)]

# Add a new fruit name column:
mydt[, fruit_name := stringr::word(desert, 2)]
```

While this works fine on small data sets, on my real data set it was taking forever (and I suspect was hanging although I killed it and restarted R after 10 minutes). For context, other character vector type operations in this data set were taking approximately 20 seconds to run, so it seems there is something especially labour intensive and computationally consuming about this function.

In contrast, if I use a regular expression with `sub()` it doesn't hang and seems to work at about the same speed as other character vector operations:

```
# Create category column with regex:
mydt[, category := sub("(^\\w+).*", "\\1", desert)]

# Create fruit name column with regex:
mydt[, fruit_name := sub("^\\w+\\s+(\\w+).*", "\\1", desert)]
```

Can anyone shed any light on the speed differences between these two approaches?  Interestingly, even with this toy example, running `system.time()` with `stringr::word()` hangs for a couple of seconds before giving the result, but that could just be because my real (large) data set is loaded in my environment.

Is `stringr::word()` somehow breaking the data.table convention of replacing by reference (creating a new column without copying the whole table)?  Somehow I thought `sub()` would be worse for this as it is presumably copying the whole string and then replacing with the bit that matches the regex pattern, but it is in fact much faster.

Any insights much appreciated!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] officer_0.4.1     flextable_0.6.9   data.table_1.14.2 lubridate_1.8.0  
 [5] forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.7       purrr_0.3.4      
 [9] readr_2.1.0       tidyr_1.1.4       tibble_3.1.6      ggplot2_3.3.5    
[13] tidyverse_1.3.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] xfun_0.28         tidyselect_1.1.1  haven_2.4.3       colorspace_2.0-2 
 [5] vctrs_0.3.8       generics_0.1.1    htmltools_0.5.2   base64enc_0.1-3  
 [9] utf8_1.2.2        rlang_0.4.12      pillar_1.6.4      glue_1.5.0       
[13] withr_2.4.2       DBI_1.1.1         gdtools_0.2.3     dbplyr_2.1.1     
[17] uuid_1.0-3        modelr_0.1.8      readxl_1.3.1      lifecycle_1.0.1  
[21] munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0      cellranger_1.1.0  zip_2.2.0        
[25] rvest_1.0.2       evaluate_0.14     knitr_1.36        fastmap_1.1.0    
[29] tzdb_0.2.0        fansi_0.5.0       broom_0.7.10      Rcpp_1.0.7       
[33] scales_1.1.1      backports_1.3.0   jsonlite_1.7.2    fs_1.5.0         
[37] systemfonts_1.0.3 digest_0.6.28     hms_1.1.1         stringi_1.7.5    
[41] grid_4.1.2        cli_3.1.0         tools_4.1.2       magrittr_2.0.1   
[45] crayon_1.4.2      pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.2    xml2_1.3.2       
[49] reprex_2.0.1      rmarkdown_2.11    assertthat_0.2.1  httr_1.4.2       
[53] rstudioapi_0.13   R6_2.5.1          compiler_4.1.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't linked to `data.table`.

`sub` relies on internal C code call:

```
function (pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, 
  fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE) 
{
  if (is.factor(x) && length(levels(x)) < length(x)) {
    sub(pattern, replacement, levels(x), ignore.case, perl, 
      fixed, useBytes)[x]
  }
  else {
    if (!is.character(x)) 
      x <- as.character(x)
    .Internal(sub(as.character(pattern), as.character(replacement), 
      x, ignore.case, perl, fixed, useBytes))
  }
}
```

whereas `stringr::word` relies on multiple `lapply`/`vapply`/`mapply` calls :

```
function (string, start = 1L, end = start, sep = fixed(" ")) 
{
  n <- max(length(string), length(start), length(end))
  string <- rep(string, length.out = n)
  start <- rep(start, length.out = n)
  end <- rep(end, length.out = n)
  breaks <- str_locate_all(string, sep)
  words <- lapply(breaks, invert_match)
  len <- vapply(words, nrow, integer(1))
  neg_start <- !is.na(start) & start < 0L
  start[neg_start] <- start[neg_start] + len[neg_start] + 
    1L
  neg_end <- !is.na(end) & end < 0L
  end[neg_end] <- end[neg_end] + len[neg_end] + 1L
  start[start > len] <- NA
  end[end > len] <- NA
  starts <- mapply(function(word, loc) word[loc, "start"], 
    words, start)
  ends <- mapply(function(word, loc) word[loc, "end"], words, 
    end)
  str_sub(string, starts, ends)
}
```

For a single string, there's not much difference:

```
desert <-"spicy apple cream"
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  stringr::word(desert, 1),
  sub("(^\\w+).*", "\\1", desert))

Unit: microseconds
                                expr  min    lq   mean median     uq   max neval
            stringr::word(desert, 1) 50.3 58.35 95.816  71.80 115.35 323.8   100
 sub("(^\\\\w+).*", "\\\\1", desert) 46.3 51.05 68.810  53.85  63.20 265.1   100
```

But if you replicate 10^6 times, `sub` is 20 times faster :

```
desert <- rep("spicy apple cream",10^6)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  stringr::word(desert, 1),
  sub("(^\\w+).*", "\\1", desert),times=5)

Unit: milliseconds
                                expr        min        lq       mean     median         uq        max
            stringr::word(desert, 1) 11605.1720 13724.731 14484.9069 14043.3454 16066.1067 16985.1798
 sub("(^\\\\w+).*", "\\\\1", desert)   696.2793   752.516   771.5857   797.5788   803.7969   807.7577
```

Answer (score 1):

For data.table, the 'stringi' library is faster than 'stringr' which is a tidyverse set of routines using the stringi library. The data.table wrapper for grepl is %ilike% which is probably more convenient, but still slower than the stringi library.

In the functions below, I am searching through about 700K plus lines of 64 fields each of VAERS data. I search two fields each line for the same terms and pass along the the search results to a pipeline. The entire search is held in the 'i' (filter) phrase of a data.table operation before I de-duplicate and dcast.

The stringi function is about three times as fast. See 'system.time' results below. The resulting tables (not shown) return the same data. Without any complicated profiling, it looks like 'stringi' uses memory more efficiently than the %ilike% grepl wrapper which appears more 'CPU bound' in operation. More information:

[https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/like.html][1]
[https://stringr.tidyverse.org/][2]

```
library(data.table)
all.heart.ilike <- function()
{
all.covid.data[
(All_symptoms %ilike% "carditis"| SYMPTOM_TEXT %ilike% "carditis")| 
(All_symptoms %ilike% "cardiac"| SYMPTOM_TEXT %ilike% "cardiac")|
(All_symptoms %ilike% "myocardial"| SYMPTOM_TEXT %ilike% "myocardial")|
(All_symptoms %ilike% "coronary"| SYMPTOM_TEXT %ilike% "coronary")|
(All_symptoms %ilike% "infarct"| SYMPTOM_TEXT %ilike% "infarct")|
(All_symptoms %ilike% "stroke"| SYMPTOM_TEXT %ilike% "stroke"),][
!duplicated(VAERS_ID_enhanced),.(count=.N),.(SEX,DECADE=AGE_YRS%/%10)][DECADE >= 1,
dcast(.SD,DECADE ~ SEX,value.var="count",fun.aggregate=fsum)]
}

library(stringi)
all.heart.stri <- function()
{
all.covid.data[
(stri_detect_regex(All_symptoms,"carditis",case_insensitive=TRUE) |stri_detect_regex(SYMPTOM_TEXT,"carditis",case_insensitive=TRUE))|
(stri_detect_regex(All_symptoms,"cardiac",case_insensitive=TRUE) |stri_detect_regex(SYMPTOM_TEXT,"cardiac",case_insensitive=TRUE))|
(stri_detect_regex(All_symptoms,"myocardial",case_insensitive=TRUE) |stri_detect_regex(SYMPTOM_TEXT,"myocardial",case_insensitive=TRUE))|
(stri_detect_regex(All_symptoms,"coronary",case_insensitive=TRUE) |stri_detect_regex(SYMPTOM_TEXT,"coronary",case_insensitive=TRUE))|
(stri_detect_regex(All_symptoms,"infarct",case_insensitive=TRUE) |stri_detect_regex(SYMPTOM_TEXT,"infarct",case_insensitive=TRUE))|
(stri_detect_regex(All_symptoms,"stroke",case_insensitive=TRUE) |stri_detect_regex(SYMPTOM_TEXT,"stroke",case_insensitive=TRUE)),][
!duplicated(VAERS_ID_enhanced),.(count=.N),.(SEX,DECADE=AGE_YRS%/%10)][DECADE >= 1,
dcast(.SD,DECADE ~ SEX,value.var="count",fun.aggregate=fsum)]
}


system.time(all.heart.ilike())
   user  system elapsed 
  47.67    0.05   47.75 

system.time(all.heart.stri())
   user  system elapsed 
  17.12    2.56   19.73
```

Comment: This is interesting, but in my case I don't know what the words are that I want to extract - I only know their position relative to the beginning of the character string.  Is there a `stringi` version of `stringr::word()`?

Comment: I would bet there is: https://stringi.gagolewski.com